# An answer is loading up blank, and other viewing anomalies

Tags: bug, android-app

I'm using the Android App v1.0.20 on a HTC Velocity 4G running Android 4.0.3. (This is a loan phone I'm using whilst my original's in for repairs, so I'm not too familiar with it.)

I've discovered that [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3649/1204) is suffering from major viewing anomalies when I view its answers in the Android App. Its first answer is *very big*, so that might have something to do with it.

**Anomaly #1:** When I first switch to the answer tab, the body of the question itself is entirely blank. This isn't the all-answers-are-empty-whilst-loading blank, but there is a very tall region where the body of an answer *should be* and *isn't*. The voting sidebar on the left shows up just fine.

> [image]

If I refresh the answer tab, then things look ok at first (they aren't) until I scroll down.

> [image]
>
> [image]

**Anomaly #2:** The rest is blank. It's like that all the way down.

**Anomaly #3:** You might notice that in both of the above screenshots, some characters along the right margin are cut off. *I can pan right* to view that text.

If I scroll down far enough, eventually the next two answers will come into view and both will load. It will seem that only once the second answer loads, *this answer* finally displays properly and all its content appears.

Which brings us to **anomaly #4:** the code block at the end is cut off horizontally. It's narrower than it should be. I can *still touch* the white space to the right where the code block should *also* be showing up, and open the code block that way.

> [image]

Comment: No repro on Nexus 4, Android 4.4.2, app 1.0.20. Might be device-specific issue. On the other hand, I find the line spacing on the screenshot is tighter than on my device.

Comment: I have noticed a difference in how this device handles loading compared to my usual device, but I thought it was just due to a version change. Usually questions and answers load empty, then their content appears and they resize to accommodate their content. (In this case tho, the resize is happening but not the actual displaying of content at first)

Comment: Now that I'm back on a HTC One running Android 4.4.2 and app version 1.0.26, I'm not getting these anomalies.

Comment: As Andrew said: no repro on same device and same versions. However, this [strange loading behaviour](http://i.stack.imgur.com/e9qYr.jpg) occurs with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22866150/2668136) on Nexus 4 (4.4.2) and app version 1.0.33.

Comment: *Note:* I have no issue when I come with the link in my above comment - I clearly see the answer. This behaviour occurs when I come to my answer on the same question from my profile, after clicked into my *top posts*. I scroll down to FerzinhaFil's post and it's empty. Maybe the longest answers have difficulties to load and/or prevent the others to be.

Comment: Is this still happening? Are you sure it's totally blank and not just "hiding" after long block of blank space as described [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248266/there-is-too-much-empty-space-in-android-app)?

Comment: @ShadowWizard This is absolutely not a case of an answer merely being very tall with some whitespace, this is answers with chunks or the entire answer rendering incorrectly or failing to do so altogether. That said, I haven't run into this bug in a while.

Comment: Interesting... retracted close vote there, wish I had android app too so I could just see for myself! :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've voted to close this as no-repro, so help me with a close vote here? :)

Comment: Sure, too bad a dev didn't have chance to look into it in time though.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I suspect the devs might consider it a _relief_ that it went away on its own. ;)