# There is too much empty space (Android app)

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, android-app

This is what my Galaxy Note 4 Android 4.4.4 shows in one of the answers to a question (it happens a lot), and it is probably not a device-specific issue I'd say.

[image: lot of whitespace]

All answers are shown properly but they often precede a lot of empty space. There were 7 full screens of empty space right after the above particular answer.

Comment: To the closevoters: This is NOT a duplicate! The proposed target is asking about when a post shows up *completely* blank, while this one is asking about when a post shows up with extra whitespace at the end.

Comment: @Doorknob good chance the other user simply did not think to scroll down enough to see the contents, no?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm not sure what you mean but the 'duplicate' suggested by you does not seem to be my problem. The person's problem is that information about the questions/answers is lost while I can see all the content clearly, only with a lot of empty space _added_ (not replaced with the content).

Comment: OK fair enough, vote retracted. If it get closed please ping me and I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: Related to [Refreshing a question in the new UI currently gets jumbly, and winds up with oddly sized posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239904/152515). (That suggestion covers something else too though, and this one by user314 is much more clear about the whitespace issue.)

Comment: I believe this is a dupe (or else, very related) to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231354/android-app-intermittently-shows-blank-body-in-questions-and-answers-multiple-s), and it should have been fixed. The reason why I said that is because [my bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249697/some-posts-are-vertically-scrollable-on-android-app?lq=1) was closed as dupe of that, and it's seemingly fixed the issue.

Comment: @AndrewT. But the questions and answers there are replaced by empty space, while here they are only preceded.

Comment: I understand what you mean, I also faced this issue before (hence, my bug report, though I admit it's not too ensuring since there's no screenshot), but it's closed as dupe of that. On the other hand, does it still occur on latest version (1.0.60)? Hint: also include the SE app version on the question to make it easier to investigate.